# Run multiple classes in the same time?

Tags: java, android, import

hi i am new to android encoding , i need a sample program that read data from the accelerometer and send them via wifi to my pc

i have the accelerometer program that works fine and also a program that send data via wifi to my pc

so the problem is that i dont know how to combine this two programs as a result i hope that the accelerometer class run in the background and return x and y values to the main program that send them

**accelerometer class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
      private SensorManager mSensorManager;
      private Sensor mAccelerometer;

      TextView title,tv,tv1,tv2;
      RelativeLayout layout;

      @Override
      public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        //get layout
        layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);

        //get textviews
        title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);   
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xval);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yval);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.zval);


      }

      @Override
      public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
      {
        // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
      }

      @Override
      public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
      {
        // Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.
        float x =  event.values[0];
        float y =  event.values[1];
        float z =  event.values[2];


        //display values using TextView
        title.setText(R.string.app_name);
        tv.setText("X axis" +"\t\t"+x);
        tv1.setText("Y axis" + "\t\t" +y);
        tv2.setText("Z axis" +"\t\t" +z);

      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume()
      {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
      }
    }
```

**wifi communication class**

```
    package net.client;

import eneter.messaging.diagnostic.EneterTrace;
import eneter.messaging.endpoints.typedmessages.*;
import eneter.messaging.messagingsystems.messagingsystembase.*;
import eneter.messaging.messagingsystems.tcpmessagingsystem.TcpMessagingSystemFactory;
import eneter.net.system.EventHandler;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity extends Activity
{
    Thread anOpenConnectionThread = new Thread();
    boolean bool = false;
    // Request message type
    // The message must have the same name as declared in the service.
    // Also, if the message is the inner class, then it must be static.
    public static class MyRequest
    {
        public String Text;
    }

    // Response message type
    // The message must have the same name as declared in the service.
    // Also, if the message is the inner class, then it must be static.
    public static class MyResponse
    {
        public int Length;
    }

    // UI controls
    private Handler myRefresh = new Handler();
    private EditText myMessageTextEditText;
    private EditText myResponseEditText;
    private Button mySendRequestBtn , mbutton1;


    // Sender sending MyRequest and as a response receiving MyResponse.
    private IDuplexTypedMessageSender<MyResponse, MyRequest> mySender;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get UI widgets.
        myMessageTextEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageTextEditText);
        myResponseEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageLengthEditText);
        mySendRequestBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendRequestBtn);
        mbutton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // Subscribe to handle the button click.
        mySendRequestBtn.setOnClickListener(myOnSendRequestClickHandler);
        mbutton1.setOnClickListener(bot);
        // Open the connection in another thread.
        // Note: From Android 3.1 (Honeycomb) or higher
        //       it is not possible to open TCP connection
        //       from the main thread.


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // Stop listening to response messages.
        mySender.detachDuplexOutputChannel();

        super.onDestroy();
    } 

    private void openConnection() throws Exception
    {
        // Create sender sending MyRequest and as a response receiving MyResponse
        IDuplexTypedMessagesFactory aSenderFactory = new DuplexTypedMessagesFactory();
        mySender = aSenderFactory.createDuplexTypedMessageSender(MyResponse.class, MyRequest.class);

        // Subscribe to receive response messages.
        mySender.responseReceived().subscribe(myOnResponseHandler);

        // Create TCP messaging for the communication.
        // Note: 10.0.2.2 is a special alias to the loopback (127.0.0.1)
        //       on the development machine.
        IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new TcpMessagingSystemFactory();
        IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel
            = aMessaging.createDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://192.168.43.44:8060/");
            //= aMessaging.createDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://192.168.1.102:8060/");

        // Attach the output channel to the sender and be able to send
        // messages and receive responses.
        mySender.attachDuplexOutputChannel(anOutputChannel);
    }

    private void onSendRequest(View v)
    {
        // Create the request message.
        final MyRequest aRequestMsg = new MyRequest();
        aRequestMsg.Text = myMessageTextEditText.getText().toString();

        // Send the request message.
        try
        {
            mySender.sendRequestMessage(aRequestMsg);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            EneterTrace.error("Sending the message failed.", err);
        }

    }

    private void onResponseReceived(Object sender,
                                    final TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse> e)
    {
        // Display the result - returned number of characters.
        // Note: Marshal displaying to the correct UI thread.
        myRefresh.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    myResponseEditText.setText(Integer.toString(e.getResponseMessage().Length));
                }
            });
    }

    private EventHandler<TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse>> myOnResponseHandler
            = new EventHandler<TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Object sender,
                            TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse> e)
        {
            onResponseReceived(sender, e);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener myOnSendRequestClickHandler = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            onSendRequest(v);
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener bot = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread anOpenConnectionThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        openConnection();
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        EneterTrace.error("Open connection failed.", err);
                    }
                }
            });


                anOpenConnectionThread.start();





          }
    };
}
```

thanks and forgive my poor english

Comment: Ahm, copy the functions of one activity into the other?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try simply copying and pasting one into the other. To my knowledge you can have multiple classes in the same file, at least in the program I use. If you can do that you should be able to run one file and both classes will be used at the same time.